# Provision a virtual server within CentOS 7?

Tags: linux, centos, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

This may be a really silly question, but I currently have a dedicated server and I have an incredible amount of redundant hardware.

I'd like to be able to provision virtual servers running various operating systems so that I can add/remove them as I want them or no longer want them. I'd like to be able to also provision a virtual server, do something that I'd like to do on the main server to validate whether it would work or not and then be able to destroy it as though it were never there.

The system specs are a Xeon E3 1225 v2, 32GB RAM, 2x2TB of Disc Space and I currently have 5 additional IP addresses at my disposal running an installation of Virtualmin for server management. All 5 IPs are fully configured to resolve at the server's address and can be used to access the server.

I've read about KVM, but there are no clear instructions on how to actually provision a server and login via SSH for example.

Help me out please :)

Thank you in advance, people.

Comment: Tutorials like you want are outside the scope of Server Fault.

Answer (score 1):

You can install oVirt on CentOS to have a web GUI you can use to manager your virtual machines. You will need an oVirt Engine to manager the nodes, so this would be the first thing you setup. Next you'd configure the oVirt software on the CentOS node and add it to the Engine.

You can follow the instructions at the oVirt website: 
http://www.ovirt.org/documentation/quickstart/quickstart-guide/

Ideally if you are going to setup that server to run other virtual machines you'd have no services/applications running on the bare-metal OS. Instead you'd create virtual machines on the hypervisor that run your applications. If you do not want to do this and are strictly looking to test new software or applications you could use a type 2 hypervisor that requires less setup work. Just note these are not designed to be used for production uses and I'd strongly advise against using a type 2 hypervisor for anything even close to production.